# i am exporting dll but GetProcAddress returning 127 error ,how to resolve it?

Tags: dllexport

```
#include "Calc.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WINERROR.H.>

typedef void (WINAPI * PCTOR) ();
int main()
{
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary (L"Calci.dll");
    if (NULL == hMod)
    {
        printf ("LoadLibrary failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    CCalc *pCCalc = (CCalc *) malloc (sizeof (CCalc));
    if (NULL == pCCalc)
    {
        printf ("memory allocation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    PCTOR pCtor = (PCTOR) GetProcAddress (hMod, "CCalc");//127 error
    int err = GetLastError();
    if (NULL == pCtor)
    {
        printf ("GetProcAddress failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    __asm { MOV ECX, pCCalc };
    pCtor ();
    return 0;
}

//dll file
#include <tchar.h>


#ifdef CALC_EXPORTS
#define CALC_API __declspec (dllexport)
#else
#define CALC_API __declspec (dllimport)
#endif

#define SOME_INSTN_BUF        260

class CALC_API CCalc
{
private:
char m_szLastUsedFunc[SOME_INSTN_BUF];

public:
    CCalc (); 

    int Add (int i, int j);
    int Sub (int i, int j);
    TCHAR* GetLastUsedFunc ();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dumpbin.exe to check the exact name of the export in the DLL. Maybe it doesn't exist at all?

If you have a chance to use import library instead of LoadLibrary API, it is better.

Comment: What? You mean dumpbin doesn't work at all, even doesn't show help message? If so, use Visual Studio Command Prompt to run dumpbin.

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking `GetProcAddress (hMod, "CCalc")`, however `"CCalc"` isn't the name of a function: it's the name of a class.

You're trying to load the address of the `CCalc::CCalc` default constructor: to do that, use a tool (e.g. `dumpbin`) to discover the "decorated" name of the constructor.

However instead of trying to dynamic-load and invoke the constructor, a more usual way to implement this functionality would be to create a static factory method in the DLL, e.g. like this:

```
class CALC_API CCalc 
{ 
public:
    static CCalc* create() { return new CCalc(); }

private:
    //doesn't need to be public because users instantiate this class using 
    //the static create method
    CCalc();  

public:
    virtual int Add (int i, int j); 
    virtual int Sub (int i, int j); 
    virtual TCHAR* GetLastUsedFunc ();

    virtual ~CCalc() {}
};
```

Then use GetProcAddress to get the address of the static CCalc::create function, which because it's static you can invoke without using assembly to mess with `ECX`.

Comment: You can also get decorated names from the `*.map` file which is optionally enabled via a linker option, or from one of the compiler listing/assembly files which you can optiionally enable via a compiler option.
Or if you have a `create` function at global scope (i.e. not declared as a member of a class), then you can use `extern "c"` to disable its name mangling (so that you can predict/know its name just from looking at the source). Or another tool to look at the binary, apart from `dumpbin.exe`, is the Dependecy Walker `depends.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use GetProcAddress for classes. This does not work. Only functions you can resolve their names are unmangled "C" functions.

For example:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) CCalc *create_calc()
{
     return new CCalc;
}
```

Now, you can resolve it using.

```
GetProcAddress(halnder,"create_calc");
```

As create_calc is not-mangled function.

Also you will have to provide abstract API class without implementation and make CCalc inherit ACalc, otherwise you'll get unresolved symbols tying to compile your application. Because actual `add` and `remove` member functions are not known to the application.

```
class ACalc {
public:
      virtual add(int i,int j) = 0;
      ...
      virtaul ~ACalc() {}
};

class CCalc : public ACalc {
public:
      virtual add(int i,int j) { ... };
      ...
};
```

And in the main program

```
ACalc *ptr= call_for_dll_function
```

Comment: I don't think it needs to be pure/abstract; instead, just defining `add` as virtual (even concrete virtual) is sufficient for the caller to use the vtable.

Comment: still confussed. showing error

"public: int __thiscall CCalc::Add(int,int)" (?Add@CCalc@@QAEHHH@Z) referenced in function _main

i have made the change as mention by  ChrisW

Comment: @user323422  you should not use CCalc class **at all** in your main program but abstract one only.